# Подскажите пожалуйста, exe`шник после сборки через Сmake и mingw32-make не запускается

Tags: c++, c, cmake, mingw, g++

У меня установлен **Cmake** и **MinGW**. Оба находятся в переменных средах. Хочу собрать проект. Использую команду **cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"**, после этого запускаю команду **mingw32-make**. Все собирается, экзешник появляется, но не запускается. **Ошибка: Точка входа в процедуру _ZdlPvj не найдена в библиотеке DLL.**

---

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall")

project(Packman)

add_executable(main main.cpp Constants.h Game.h Ghost.h ICharacter.h Packman.h 
Pellet.h setConsoleAtributes.h Game.cpp Ghost.cpp Pellet.cpp Packman.cpp 
SetConsoleAtributes.cpp)
```

---

Запускаю через g++ командой: **g++ -o name.exe -std=c++14 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ main.cpp Constants.h Game.h Ghost.h ICharacter.h Packman.h Pellet.h setConsoleAtributes.h Game.cpp Ghost.cpp Pellet.cpp Packman.cpp SetConsoleAtributes.cpp** и все собирается. Но через Cmake не получается. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Думаю, что в статической линковке, но я не уверен. Если да, то как правильно ее настроить через Cmake? Спасибо, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: *"не найдена в библиотеке DLL"* Что, прямо так и написано? Там вроде должно быть название библиотеки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, так и написано, и просто путь в конце еще показывается после этого: "Точка входа в процедуру _ZdlPvj не найдена в библиотеке DLL C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\go_work\build\main.exe"

Comment: Гугл говорит, что `_ZdlPvj` - это `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)`. Вангую, что нужно dll-ки стандартной библиотеки положить в папку с `.exe` (если не линковать статически).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а что за dll-ки стандартной библиотеки? где их нужно взять? в dll-ках немного плаваю) у меня есть код, состоящий из .h .cpp и файл CMakeLists.txt в директории, я его пропускаю через cmake и mingw32-make. Оно мне генерит обьекты и экзешник, который выдает такую ошибку. Если можно, как правильно линковать статически через cmake?

Comment: Чтобы линковать статически попробуйте `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"`. *"что за dll-ки стандартной библиотеки"* Ну вы же зачем-то флажки `-static-*` добавляли. Без них вашей программе нужно несколько dll-ок, которые она ищет в папке, где находится, и в `PATH`. Каких именно - зависит от сборки gcc, у меня `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libwinpthread-1.dll`. Если программа находит в `PATH` неподходящие версии этих dll, то иногда возникают странные ошибки. Попробуйте найти эти dll-ки в папке `bin` компилятора и скопировать в папку с вашей программной.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо огромное, запустилось!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка состоит в том, что программа линковалась **динамически** и искала необходимые ей dll-ки, которые она не смогла найти. Для того, чтобы слинковать **статически**, нужно в `CMakeLists.txt` добавить `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)`. После этого будет запускаться.